# Why is this variable of type optional...?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm so confused - I've written the same code numerous times and never had this problem. My knowledge of python doesn't go far beyond self taught stuff to build a rest api with flask framework for my iOS apps. When I make my api call to retrieve some data for this specific path, MySQL keeps returning 'error' because for some reason the variable I pass is being passed as an optional type ( I think? - b/coz the print statement prints: Optional(1) )

Can someone explain what is going on here? And why this same exact code worked fine in my other paths? I've even tried casting it as a string. The function that makes the api call in my iOS app only accepts a string as parameter as well...Running the MySQL query with a hard coded value always works.

***** thwart is what i renamed MySQLdb escape_string *****

The query function:

```
def checkAnswers(gameId):

    print("inside check answers function")
    print(gameId)

    id = str(gameId)

    c, conn = connection()

    data = c.execute("SELECT answer_one, answer_two FROM games WHERE game_id='%s'" % (thwart(id)))

    if data:
        return c.fetchall()
    return "error"
```

Inside the main.py file under the correct path I have this code snippet: (print(data) always prints 'error')

```
print("inside check answers path")
json = request.get_json()

gameId = str(json["gameId"])

data = checkAnswers(gameId)

print("answer data ----->")
print(data)
```

Comment: Check the value of `thwart(id)` in your `checkAnswers` function. While you're doing that please alter your code to use the second parameter of the `execute` method and don't use string formatting with `%`. Your way to do it opens a giant security breach.

Comment: @matthias thwart(id) is also printing Optional(1), just like the print(gameId). I am unsure how to do this without string formatting with %. Thanks for your feedback so far

Comment: Concerning the main question: `thwart` seems to be your function. You should know what it returns and get the value you really want. Concerning the second parameter of `execute`: [Read the documentation of `execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15)

Comment: If you're using sqlite the documentation is there: [sqlite3 — DB-API 2.0 interface for SQLite databases](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: What is `thwart()`?

Comment: thank you. i've updated that part. but this code is copy/ pasted from my other api calls. why is it only not working here? why all of a sudden is it optional and why isn't casting it as a string not working anywhere

Comment: thwart is what I call escape_string from MySQLdb @DanielRoseman

Comment: In any case `Optional` is not a type in Python. Are you sure that's not the value you are sending from your iOS code? It apparently *is* a type in Swift; could you have stringified that by mistake?

Comment: @DanielRoseman no, im definitely sending a string, i triple checked that part haha. The iOS function i wrote won't even accept type optional

Answer (score 0):

`execute` has no return value, checking it, does not make any sense, just check for empty result of `fetchall`:

```
def checkAnswers(gameId):
    print("inside check answers function")
    print(gameId)
    id = str(gameId)
    c, conn = connection()
    c.execute("SELECT answer_one, answer_two FROM games WHERE game_id=%s", (thwart(id),))
    return c.fetchall()
```

Comment: I was under the impression that it would return a bool value basically. so if it was a failed query it would hit the 'error' message. I use this logic in other api calls and it works as expected @Daniel

Comment: @user7804097: Most functions & methods in Python don't use their return values to indicate success vs. failure.  If something fails, they just raise an exception instead.

Comment: Also this didn't work. it's returning an empty set because its still searching using the optional variable type

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a xcode bug [Queue all iOS/ xcode insults]. Even though I was casting the variable to a string properly in xcode, it was being sent as optional...all I did was clean the project code and restart xcode and it was working as expected..... 3 hours and a headache later. what a fix....

THANKS TO ALL WHO CONTRIBUTED to this as it was basically an unanswerable question.